# Fantasy story about a trinity where one member is a dog

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago, I read a novel? short story? about a trinity in a fantasy setting where one member is a dog, and I would really like to find it again so I could reread it. I don't remember all that much, but the beginning really stuck with me.

It starts off in a city under siege, from the perspective of a dog whose human is a wizard who has gone outside of the house for some reason. The dog can smell his? her? human outside the house, but then the smell *cools* and turns to meat. The dog leaves the house to look for why her? human turned to meat, and meets the second member of the trinity, who I think is a woman, but I don't remember much from there.

Edit: I don't remember the names of the characters (dog, human wizard or second member of the trinity), but it would have been in the late 80's or early 90's, and it would have been an adult story, not YA or for children. I don't believe the story went into the details of what type of magic the wizard could cast, other than it was fairly standard fantasy fare for the time. What made it memorable to me was that a significant part of the story was told from the dog's point of view.

Comment: Is the word "trinity" used in the book/s?

Comment: I believe so - I tried doing a Google search, but that turned up all kinds of stuff where the main character is named Trinity etc.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the name of the dog? How long ago was "a long time ago"? What kind of magic could the wizard do? What was the female character's name? Was the story for adults or children?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[The Wizard's Dog](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/g/eric-kahn-gale/wizards-dog.htm)* (2017) by Eric Kahn Gale?

> Meet Nosewise. He’s spunky. He’s curious. And he’s a dog who can’t
> understand why his pack mates Merlin and Morgana spend all day
> practicing magic tricks. If it’s a trick they want, he’s the dog to
> ask! He can already Sit!, Stay!, and Roll Over!
>
> But there’s no way
> Nosewise is Stay!ing when his master and best friend, Merlin, is
> kidnapped. There’s nothing Nosewise won’t do to get Merlin back, even
> if it means facing the strange Fae people and their magic-eating
> worms, or tangling with the mysterious Sword in the Stone. But it may
> take more than sniffing out a spell to do it!
>
> [image]

Comment: I don't think so - your description reads as if Merlin is still alive, whereas in the story I read the human was very definitely dead and the dog was basically homeless from that point on.